# Delete local file after upload to Azure

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-storage

Trying to delete local backup files after they have been uploaded to Azure storage, gets the following error:

> Get-ChildItem : Cannot find path
>   'C:\Windows\system32\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Common.Storage.ResourceModel.AzureStorageBlob'
>   because it does not exist.

When running the following code:

```
$BackupDir= 'C:\BackupDir'
$AzureDir= Get-AzureStorageBlob -Context $context -Container $containername -blob $file.name
Get-ChildItem $AzureDir | ForEach-Object
{
    $FileInBackup= $AzureDir + $_.Name
    If (Test-Path $FileInBackup) {Remove-Item $FileInBackup}
}
```

Why is it looking in C:\Windows*blahblah*?

If I print variable $AzureDir to screen, I see all my blobs.

---

Basically, it's probably obvious but what I want to do is check each file in my backup DIR and if it exists in Azure, delete it, if not, continue on to the upload step. I can share the rest of my code if need be.

---

**RESOLUTION UPDATE:**

Thanks to @OmegaMan, who pointed me down the right path, I was able to fix my issue. Here is what I'm now using. It's cycling through 4 'blobs' correctly and using the results correctly:

```
$BackupDir = 'C:\BackupDir'
$AzureFiles = Get-AzureStorageBlob -Context $context -Container $containername -blob *.name
foreach ($AzureFile in $AzureFiles)
{
    $FileInBackup = $AzureFile.name
    If (Test-Path $BackupDir\$FileInBackup)
    {
        Remove-Item $FileInBackup
    }
}
```

Comment: What Windows *build* are you on (type "winver" into start)?

Comment: @tambre, this machine is running Server 2016 Datacenter (v1607, build 14393.1770).

Comment: Might be useless info, but PS on this machine is: 5.1.14393.1770.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to use `$AzureDir` in one instance to hold all the blob infos, which is fine but then the line  `$FileInBackup= $AzureDir + $_.Name` seems to think `$AzureDir` is a literal directory name.

It appears you need to rectify where the base directory is instead of `$AzureDir` in those instances.

Comment: Thank you @OmegaMan!

That set me down the right path. I was able to get my script to properly check 4 different containers and loop through each file name with your tip of rectifying the base directory. I've updated my original post with the result thanks to your suggestion.